# 91 octane misfire but 95 or 98 no misfire

Tags: fuel-system

My car has one strange issue which affecting starting and misfire.

With 91 octane starting is good but misfire randomly at idle with air con on.

With 95 or 98 octane starting is very difficult I have to do 3 times try to start up . 
However, no misfire.

- when driving the car is ok 
  Only misfire at idle at traffic lights.
  With this issue I have driven 30000km. But car hasn't stopped yet.
  Car I bought 175000km then now 200000km almost.
  I didn't know when the issue occurred coz previous owner.

I have replaced fuel filter , pump , temperature sensor with ecu sender, timing tensioner , cam sensor , crank sensor, tps sensor, sparks , leads, coils, injectors and starter moter.

Please someone know this issue let me know! 
I love mine.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the car you're talking about?

Comment: Overly advanced timing at idle?  Bad/clogged Idle air control?  I do want to know where you get  98 octane . . . somewhere far away, I suspect.

Comment: 2004  Mitsubishi challenger

Comment: Air control moter changed.

Comment: At idle rpm just drop 100? Then back

Comment: Driving is perfect so  very difficult

Comment: @SteveRacer - I'm sure the OP is talking about RON and not an average of (RON+MON)/2 ([or AKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_rating#Anti-Knock_Index_(AKI)_or_(R+M)/2)) as we do here in the States. RON by itself has a higher number than the AKI would show.

Comment: I would use an OBD tool and make certain the ECU is getting the "AC on" idle compensation.  I understand the "difficult" nature of diagnosis, but I would look at some OBD II *pids* parameters to see if everything is reasonable.  Try to examine airflow sensor at idle for clues.  Also check the knock sensor output if it has one.  Are there any codes, even of the "pending" type?